# Python: .loc sometimes placing values in the wrong column

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a large CSV file that I read in with pandas and then create a new (empty) column:

```
voters = pd.read_csv('voters.csv')
voters['donor'] = ''
```

Later, I attempt to update some of the rows for this new `donor` column:

```
for person in matches:
    voters.loc[person,'donor'] = True
```

This almost works fine, except occasionally I see `True` in a nonexistent column adjacent to the `donor` column:

[image: libre office view of the resulting csv file]

Edit: Below is a screenshot of my terminal output of a few sample lines out of the CSV file. It appears that the last couple of columns are placed onto a new line, which may be related to this issue.

[image: example lines in csv]

Comment: Hi @ColinG, How did you get the values to the spreadsheet? Looking into the code inteself, no `True`  value should have gone to another column.

Comment: @jib_gouveia The original screenshot I included is of opening the resulting CSV in LibreOffice. I included an additional screenshot in the original post that may help troubleshooting.

Comment: On the dataframe, before extracting again to CSV, are the values alright? Just so we can understand where the problem comes from

Comment: @jib_gouveia I printed out to console the rows shortly before the DF is saved to CSV, they appear to be fine.

Comment: Ok, so the problem isn't on the `.loc`. Maybe you should ask differently the question. It seems to be a problem in saving the file, but I can't really tell without the full information